# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_typeshed'

Tags: python, class

I'm a beginner programmer and we were tasked to create a `class` on Google Colab.

This is the code that I created:

```
from _typeshed import Self

class Customers:
  greeting = 'Welcome to the Coffee Palace!'
  
  def __init__(self, name, beverage, food, total):
    self.name = name
    self.beverage = beverage
    self.food = food
    self.total = total

c1 = Customers()
c2 = Customers()

c1.name = 'Samirah'
c1.beverage = 'Iced caffe latte'
c1.food = 'Cinnamon roll'
c1.total = 225

c2.name = 'Jerry'
c2.beverage = 'Caramel macchiato'
c2.food = 'Glazed doughnut'
c2.tota = 230

print('Samirah wants to drink '+ c1.beverage)
print('Jerry wants to eat '+ c2.food)
```

But then this error keeps popping:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-d30ac4e0ffe7> in <module>()
----> 1 from _typeshed import Self
      2 #CodeHere
      3 class Customers:
      4   greeting = 'Welcome to the Coffee Palace!'
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_typeshed'
```

I don't know how to fix this or if there are actually some errors in my code, so your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should be able to remove that line -- I suspect your IDE erroneously added it due to a typo?

Comment: Hmm, I did find some typos but they weren't breaking the code.

Comment: my guess is you accidentally typed `Self` and your IDE "helpfully" inserted the bad import